# Propositions that can't be used to distinguish possible worlds

Tags: modal-logic, possible-worlds

Are there known ways of formalizing the notion of propositions that *can't be targeted by counterfactuals* in a coherent way? Or of propositions that are outside the scope of the framework in question?

As a quick example of what I mean, here's an example of extending a modal logic (let's say S5 for concreteness) with a non-primitive modal operator `Y` that attempts to capture some of the intuition I'm going for.

Let's take a proposition like `The number 4 exists.`. There are many, many ways of analyzing that proposition including denying that it has a meaning or denying that it has a truth value. Let's suppose we're working in a framework that accepts that `The number 4 exists.` has a truth value, but doesn't commit to a particular truth value. Let's further suppose that our framework imposes the additional constraint that all possible worlds in our framework have the same truth value for `The number 4 exists.`.

In a certain sense, we've said something rather interesting about our notion of possibility/necessity, namely that *it isn't powerful enough to consider questions like the existence of numbers but doesn't make a commitment either*. Another way of looking at it is this is the "inside view" of questions outside the scope of the framework we're working in.

I can think of one sort of silly way to formalize this with a derived modal operator `Y` which means

```
Yx = ALxLNx     either x is necessarily true or x is necessarily false
```

`Y` has some nice properties like closure under negation.

```
Yx  if and only if   YNx
```

`Y` is also closed under conjunction.

```
Ya and Yb  implies  YKab
```

And `{N,K}` is functionally complete, which is good but hardly definitive.

Comment: Forster calls predicates that satisfy ∀x(P(x)↔□P(x)) noncontingent, and characterizes modal machinery (accessibility relations; relations of satisfaction between propositions and worlds; relations of habitation between objects and worlds; relations of correspondence or identity across worlds; the property of being a possible world) as noncontingent, see [Modal Aether](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~tf/modalrealism.pdf). Of course, the identity predicate is famously noncontingent, according to Kripke.

Comment: @Conifold, the identity predicate is binary. Are we / is Kripke quantifying over the left and right possible world independently or together?

Comment: P can be a multi-place predicate, x is meant to be a tuple of variables, and ∀ quantifies over each. See [necessity of identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_of_identity) for Kripke's arguments.